# Modifying receiver with a method on value?

Tags: go

```golang
package matrix

import (
    "errors"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

// Matrix matrix inteface
type Matrix interface {
    Rows() [][]int
    Cols() [][]int
    Set(r, c, val int) bool
}

// matrix implements the interface Matrix
type matrix struct {
    data [][]int
    rows int
    cols int
}

// New returns a valid matrix created from the input
func New(input string) (Matrix, error) {
    var m matrix
    rows := strings.Split(input, "\n")
    for r, row := range rows {
        rowElements := strings.Fields(row)

        switch {
        case r == 0:
            m.rows, m.cols = len(rows), len(rowElements)
            matrix, err := allocateMemory(m.rows, m.cols)
            if err != nil {
                return invalidMatrix()
            }
            m.data = matrix
        case len(rowElements) != m.cols:
            return invalidMatrix()
        }

        for c, element := range rowElements {
            element, err := strconv.Atoi(element)
            if err != nil {
                return invalidMatrix()
            }
            m.data[r][c] = element
        }
    }
    return m, nil
}

// invalidMatrix returns the error indicating the
// provided matrix is invalid
func invalidMatrix() (Matrix, error) {
    return nil, errors.New("invalid matrix")
}

// allocateMemory allocates a 2D slice of int having size RxC
func allocateMemory(R, C int) ([][]int, error) {
    if R < 1 || C < 1 {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid matrix")
    }
    matrix := make([][]int, R)
    for r := range matrix {
        matrix[r] = make([]int, C)
    }
    return matrix, nil
}

// Set sets the given value at (r,c) in the matrix,
// if (r,c) belongs to the matrix.
func (m matrix) Set(r, c, val int) bool {
    switch {
    case r < 0 || c < 0:
        return false
    case r >= m.rows || c >= m.cols:
        return false
    default:
        m.data[r][c] = val
        return true
    }
}

// order defines the order the matrix to export
// two useful values are columnMajor and rowMajor
type order int

const (
    columnMajor order = iota
    rowMajor
)

// Cols returns columns of the matrix.
func (m matrix) Cols() [][]int {
    return m.export(columnMajor)
}

// Rows returns rows of the matrix.
func (m matrix) Rows() [][]int {
    return m.export(rowMajor)
}

// export return the matrix in the required order;
// either columnMajor or rowMajor.
func (m matrix) export(o order) [][]int {
    var matrix [][]int
    var err error
    switch o {
    case columnMajor:
        matrix, err = allocateMemory(m.cols, m.rows)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        for r, row := range m.data {
            for c, element := range row {
                matrix[c][r] = element
            }
        }
    case rowMajor:
        matrix, err = allocateMemory(m.rows, m.cols)
        if err != nil {
            return nil
        }
        for r, row := range m.data {
            copy(matrix[r], row)
        }
    }
    return matrix
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding why the method Set() is able to modify the data of the struct. I had an understanding that methods defined on values cannot do that. I have tried to compare it with another problem where I cannot modify the content of receiver but in this case it just works. A test file for this code is available at [test file](https://exercism.io/tracks/go/exercises/matrix/solutions/fcddc76786d94a8295c8c73cebe60f40). Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: The Set method modifies the slice's underlying array.  The struct fields are not modified.  See [Go Slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) if  you are not familiar with slices.

Comment: I was also guessing the same this but it does not seem consistent with the another example I have. Method parseString() in the following example cannot modify the slice if defined on a value, any particular reason for that? [https://exercism.io/tracks/go/exercises/luhn/solutions/c3f1cd930f67425e86799bf01d36ee97](https://exercism.io/tracks/go/exercises/luhn/solutions/c3f1cd930f67425e86799bf01d36ee97)

Comment: Modifying the slice's underlying array is different from modifying the slice value as shown in the parseString() xample.  A slice value is a (ptr, len, cap) where ptr is a pointer to the slice's underlying array. See more details [here](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro#TOC_4.).

Answer (score 6):

The reason `Set` can modify the *contents* of the slice is that the slice is a *reference value*. Your other example (in the comment) attempts to assign the field holding the slice, and this won't work - because it's working on a copy. See this code sample:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Holder struct {
    s []int
    v []int
}

func (h Holder) Set() {
    // This will successfully modify the `s` slice's contents
    h.s[0] = 99

    // This will assign a new slice to a copy of the v field,
    // so it won't affect the actual value on which this
    // method is invoked. 
    h.v = []int{1, 2, 3}
}

func main() {
    var h Holder
    h.s = []int{10, 20, 30}
    h.v = []int{40, 50, 60}

    fmt.Println("before Set:", h)
    
    h.Set()
    fmt.Println("after Set:", h)
}
```

[You can run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bVL-DHdO1F_G), and it prints:

```
before Set: {[10 20 30] [40 50 60]}
after Set: {[99 20 30] [40 50 60]}
```

What happens here is that even though `Set` gets a copy of `h`, and hence `h.s` is a copy too, but both copies point to the same underlying slice, so the contents can be modified. Read [this post](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) for all the details.

Answer (score 3):

A slice value contains (ptr, len, cap) where `ptr` is a pointer to the slice's underlying array.  The `Set` method modifies the slice's underlying array by dereferencing the pointer.  The slice value, stored in the field, is not modified.

The [Go Language blog post on slices](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro#TOC_4.) describes the slice memory layout in more detail.